# How to export svg or eps from Flash at runtime with actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possibble at all.. I've search around and it seems like its not possible. I know you can export png, jpg (using https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) and pdf, but how about vector graphics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [as3svgrendererlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/)?

It allows you to manipulate and render SVGs in actionscript 3.0, Flash 10, and Flex 3.0+ at runtime.

Another one is [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/).

Comment: Cool thanks, I had a quick look at as3svgrendererlib - and it seems that its just to display svg, not to export it as a svg file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'd likely have to write SVG or PDF then use a second tool to convert from whatever to EPS. Easier with AIR or a webservice than a pure web swf.